# CakePHP AclExtras Plug In not found

Tags: cakephp, acl

I've been screwing around a bit with the CakePHP framework. 
I was upto this part: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html 
And I've downloaded the plug-in and placed it into the plugin folder
This is what my plugin folder looks like (C:\xampp\htdocs\nublet\app\plugin )

> -AclExtras(DIR)
>   -AclExtrasShell.php (FILE)
>   --Console(DIR)
>   ---Command(DIR)
>   ----AclExtrasShell.php (FILE)

Now this is what it says when i try to run the command.

```
C:\>cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync

Error: Plugin AclExtras could not be found.
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Nublet\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(364): CakePlugin::path('AclExtra
s')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Nublet\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(225): App::pluginPath('AclExtras
')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Nublet\lib\Cake\Core\App.php(542): App::path('Console/Command
', 'AclExtras')
#3 [internal function]: App::load('AclExtrasShell')
#4 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('AclExtrasShell')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Nublet\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(216): class_exist
s('AclExtrasShell')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Nublet\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(167): ShellDispat
cher->_getShell('AclExtras.AclEx...')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Nublet\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispatc
her->dispatch()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Nublet\app\Console\cake.php(33): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#9 {main}
```

Tried this: 
https://github.com/markstory/acl_extras/issues/8
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887895/cakephp-2-1-authentication-aclextras-does-not-populate-acos-table

What can I do?

Greetings,
Harm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using bake on Windows, I've found you need to be a bit more specific sometimes.

```
C:\>cake -app "C:\xampp\htdocs\Nublet\app" AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync
```

You can always just run `cake` to see what directories it's guessing it should use.

Comment: is true this fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

@jeremyharris:

i have the same problem in linux ubuntu, but your answer solved it :

my path to cakephp : /var/www/CMS/cakephp

also:

open terminal and enter code:

`cd /var/www/CMS/cakephp/lib/Cake`

`Console/cake -app "/var/www/CMS/cakephp/app" AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync`