# Can't make ApiGenerator to work

Tags: php, cakephp, cake-console

I downloaded ApiGenerator from GitHub and pasted it inside app/Plugin/ApiGenerator, and edited the bootstrap to `CakePlugin::load('ApiGenerator');`. Then I wanted to do the next step, that is going to cake console and input the following line:

```
cake ApiGenerator.ApiIndex initdb
```

But it returns me the following error message:

```
Error: Plugin ApiGenerator could not be found.
```

I changed the bootstrap to `CakePlugin::loadAll();` but still I got the same error.
I tried to change the line `cake ApiGenerator` to `cake DebugKit` (which I have installed and working) to see if it's just ApiGenerator or not, but it shows me the same error, which means that the cake console isn't recognizing any plugin, although I have DebugKit successfully operating.

So, any ideas what is wrong with ApiGenerator? Is there a way (a variable or something) that can tell me which plugins are already operating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer myself, lol.
Refering to this post: [CakePHP AclExtras Plug In not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191031/cakephp-aclextras-plug-in-not-found), it was cake console's fault on windows.

For those who run on the same luck, just add the path to app folder. That means:

```
cake -app "C:\www_dir\cake_project\app" ApiGenerator.ApiIndex initdb
```

Hooray me!